# Do companies provide external help/consultancy when an employee face problem in projects?

Tags: consultants

I have been working on a project since 7 months. This is my first job. I am the one responsible for the project as no one in my office is from this domain. My project includes  5 modules and I have completed 3 modules. My Team leader and manager are quite happy with my performance. But I am now facing few problems with the remaining 2 modules. The hardware for which I am making software is not responding. I have told this to my team leader but all he says is that problem is in my software because hardware is designed by someone who has 15 years of experience. I am really facing problem and don't know how to solve it. I need some help who can guide. I have asked my team leader to purchase a tool to debug hardware but he refused as its very costly.

How can I approach to my manager/team leader and can ask for some external help to resolve this issue?

Comment: Suggestion: Team programming. Ask an experienced co-worker to look through the code with you. Often, simply trying to explain exactly what your code is doing is enough to flush out the bad assumption; if not they may spot it since they're coming to the code without preconceptions about what  was intended (which might not be exactly what you wrote). If they can't help you find it, you have a stronger case for blaming the hardware... though you should think about how your boss will feel if that money gets spent and it's your software after all!

Comment: Is the hardware for the last two modules different from the first three? If it is can you contact the hardware designer of 15 years to get the needed feedback on how or what's needed in your software to make it work as intended?

Comment: "because hardware is designed by someone who has 15 years of experience". This is nonsense! There could be a thousand reasons why the hardware could be defective. Your boss sounds like he has no experience. Is there (formal or informal) support in place for the hardware? If so, isolate the issues with unit tests, and start submitting bug reports to it. If there is no system in place, create your own public blog/tracker to describe these issues yourself (with the permission of your employer). As to the debugging hardware, try to borrow/rent that kind of hardware from colleagues in your field.

Comment: Keep in mind that the original manufacturer/designer may even be willing to loan you that kind of equipment (without charging you for it). At least, it wouldn't hurt to ask if that's possible. Just explain to that person (or persons) the problem that you're facing, and that you company just doesn't have the budget to buy the right debugging hardware.

Comment: Thanks everyone I am writing down the bugs and have written a mail to TL for a discussion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a bit surprised that nobody mentioned to request a meeting with you, your manager, and the hardware guy of 15 years experience. Basically make the meeting not about finger pointing but rather say that you're having trouble speaking to the hardware and you'd like to narrow it down. In the meeting, show code and show proof that it isn't responding but don't point finger. Say something like, "I tried responding to your hardware and expected a response of XXXYYYZZZ and instead I get back a null signal. Can you explain why that is?" Then having him speak outloud his proof that it works and then ask for guidance on what you're doing wrong. Eventually he'll have to make it work for your code because he would be unable to explain otherwise.

The worst case in this meeting is that it can also expose something you did wrong. It could be you forgot something or didn't read the documentations right. I think sitting down and talking with the hardware builder would help.

Comment: `The worst case in this meeting is that it can also expose something you did wrong` - IMO that's a positive outcome.  So long as it's approached correctly, as you mentioned, then the purpose of the meeting is finding a resolution to the problem.  If the resolution is fixing an unknown bug in the OP's code rather than a hardware issue, it's still a resolution and the project can move forward.

Comment: It strikes me that the *first* thing that you should do if your software can't talk to the custom hardware is to ask the hardware guy how it's *supposed* to work.  Then you can work together to sort the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, they would if it is within their budget constraints.

For example, my team was trained by professionals from AWS when we were setting up the architecture.

However, **you** have to do the necessary groundwork and research about the training programmes available and the cost of training.

So, this is what you do:

1. As said above, do the necessary groundwork and research about the training programmes available and the cost of training
2. Narrow down to about 3-5 such programmes and detailed information about each. Also include the pros and cons of each. Please keep the costs in mind while narrowing down the list
3. Present this detailed survey to your manager and let him make the necessary decision about whether to move ahead with the training or not. If yes, then what programme should he be moving ahead with

Answer (score 1):

The usual path would be: a. You try to solve the problem. b. You read up on everything you can find, then you try **very hard** to solve the problem. c. You step back, relax, and check if you haven't done anything stupid that keeps it from working. It happens. You say "Oh my god, how stupid of me", and solve the problem easily. d. You check if there is anyone else in the company who can help you solve the problem. e. You discuss with your manager whether it is possible to go ahead without ever solving the problem. You also discuss whether the problem can be solved at all, and how much better than you someone who can solve the problem would have to be. f. The company hires a contractor who can solve the problem or tell that it is impossible to solve.

(I remember having a poor colleague who got lumbered with the job to get smart cards working with our product. I avoided it because I just *knew* it would be trouble. And the devilish things react very badly to any errors during development and see it as a hacker attack and lock up, and then nothing works).